# Statistically significant win rate

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, binomial-distribution, model-evaluation, games

I'm playing around with AIs for [Onitama](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/160477/onitama), a 2 player pefect knowledge game.

I want to compare the strengths of different AIs by measuring their wins and loses and then testing for statistical significance.

[image: Game Results]

- The results are from the perspective of the row
- "draw" really means "50 turns with no winner")
- "min_max_X" means "min_max searching to depth X"

My first attempt is to use a binomial test.
Ignoring draws, my null hypothesis is that equal strength AIs win 50% of the time.

I calculated P-values using [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binom_test.html)

```
p_value = stats.binom_test(x=result["win"], n=result["win"] + result["lose"], p=0.5, alternative='two-sided')
```

[image: P-values based on previous results]

These results seem reasonable to me, assuming I'm interpreting right:

- The closer the P-value is to 0, the more likely null-hypothesis is to be wrong
- "random" has low P-values against min-max, as expected
- For AIs playing themselves, we get high P-values, as expected

Is my approach valid for this situation, and is there a better/more common way?

Comment: Staying closer to the usual terminology of hypothesis testing, it would be better for the first bullet to say, "The null hypothesis is rejected for P-values near 0." Strictly speaking (in frequentist statistics), a test of hypothesis makes statements about the data (which are either consistent with the null hypothesis or not), not statements not about the "probability" of the null hypothesis. // I'm not sure about the structure of the experiment; testing might be more efficient if you could define the 'game' so Draws do not occur.

Answer (score 1):

I tried several of these computations in R using `binom.test`, obtaining results that match yours.

In particular, for 'Random vs Random', I got:

```
binom.test(21, 21+17, alt="two")

        Exact binomial test

data:  21 and 21 + 17
number of successes = 21, number of trials = 38, p-value = 0.6271
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.3829908 0.7137585
sample estimates:
probability of success 
             0.5526316
```

Also, for 'min_max3 va min_max2':

```
binom.test(21, 21+10, alt="two")

        Exact binomial test

data:  21 and 21 + 10
number of successes = 21, number of trials = 31, p-value = 0.07076
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.4862702 0.8331764
sample estimates:
probability of success 
             0.6774194
```

---

Sometimes, this is called a 'sign test' where Wins are called `+`, Losses `-`, and Draws are ignored. For the first example above ('Random vs Random'),
the P-value for a two-sided test can be computed, by symmetry, as $2P(X \le 17)= 0.6271,$ where
$X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=38,\, p=1/2).$

```
2*pbinom(17, 21+17, 1/2)
[1] 0.6271026
```

[image]